# Mostrar datos null en consulta linq

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una consulta en `linq` y esta funciona bien, pero en algunas ocaciones las columnas de las filas deben ser marcadas con `null` y cuando estan `null` mi consulta se salta ese registro y me muestra las demas.

`Clase:`

```
public class Consultas
        {
            public string Radicado { get; set; }
            public DateTime? Fecha { get; set; }
            public string Radicador { get; set; }
            public string Documento { get; set; }
            public string Soporte { get; set; }
            public string Proveedor { get; set; }
            public string Factura { get; set; }
            public string Destinatario { get; set; }
            public string Observaciones { get; set; }
            public string EstadoA { get; set; }
            public DateTime? FechaDoc { get; set; }
            public string UsuarioDoc { get; set; }
            public string EstadoB { get; set; }
            public string UserCon { get; set; }
            public DateTime? FechaEntrega { get; set; }
            public string EstadoC { get; set; }
            public DateTime? Fecha_Reci { get; set; }
        }
```

`Linq:`

```
private void cargarGridSeguimiento()
        {
            /*LLENAR DATAGRID*/
            using (SICAP_AGROSANEntities en = new SICAP_AGROSANEntities())
            {

                var query_se = from d in en.tblDocumental.ToList()
                            join c in en.tblCompanias on d.empresa equals c.idCompania
                            join u in en.tblUsuarios on d.usu_radica equals u.idUsuario
                            join doc in en.tblUsuarios on d.usu_doc equals doc.idUsuario
                            join con in en.tblUsuarios on d.user_con equals con.idUsuario
                            join r in en.tblDestinatarios on d.usu_remi equals r.idDestinatario
                            where d.empresa == 1
                            orderby d.radicado ascending
                            select new Consultas()
                            {
                                Radicado = d.radicado,
                                Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(d.fechaLog),
                                Radicador = u.Nombre,
                                Documento = d.documento,
                                Soporte = d.soporte,
                                Proveedor = d.remi_prov,
                                Factura = d.asun_fact,
                                Destinatario = r.Destinatario,
                                Observaciones = d.observaciones,
                                EstadoA = d.estadoA,
                                FechaDoc = Convert.ToDateTime(d.fecha_dev),
                                UsuarioDoc = doc.Nombre,
                                EstadoB = d.estadoB,
                                UserCon = con.Nombre,
                                FechaEntrega = Convert.ToDateTime(d.fecha_entrega),
                                EstadoC = d.estadoC,
                                Fecha_Reci = Convert.ToDateTime(d.fecha_reci)
                            };
                dgvConsultasAG.ItemsSource = query_se;
            }
        }
```

`Data:`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Trate de usar `string.IsNullOrEmpty` pero no consigo mostrar las
>   filas que contengan valores `Null` en mi datagrid.

Comment: a que te refieres con que se salta el registro ? eso comportamiento de saltar cuado armas un linq no existe. Por ejemplo `d.fecha_dev` de que tipo de dato se trata ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini el campo `d.fecha_dev` es tipo `fecha`, cuando digo salta es, por ejeplo: tengo una lista con 3 registros pero si el registro 2 tiene campos `Null` mi `datagrid` solo esta mostrando el registro 1 y 3, me explique bien?

Comment: estas seguro que eso no es porque debe a que defines un filtro en el `where d.empresa == 1` ? el null en un campo no causa ese efecto de mostrar un registro o no

Comment: Si seguro, los unicos campos que no se muestran son los que tengan algun dato como null

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el codigo he inspeccionas la respuesta de linq este devuelve los registros que dices tienen null ? para ver si el problema es en el linq o cuando asignas al grid

Comment: Ya lo puse y los registros que llegan ninguno tienen Null

Comment: de casualidad alguno de estos campos null lo estas usando en un `join` ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Si, en este `join con in en.tblUsuarios on d.user_con equals con.idUsuario`

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes una propidad que puede tomar un valo null en una relacion no se puede usar el `join` directamente ya que en caso de no existir relacion no traera el registro.

Para estos casos donde la relacion es opcional se utiliza el `left join`

[Realizar operaciones de combinación externa izquierda](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

Entonces quedaria algo como ser

```
var query_se = from d in en.tblDocumental.ToList()
                join c in en.tblCompanias on d.empresa equals c.idCompania
                join u in en.tblUsuarios on d.usu_radica equals u.idUsuario
                join doc in en.tblUsuarios on d.usu_doc equals doc.idUsuario
                join con in en.tblUsuarios on d.user_con equals con.idUsuario into userGroup
                join r in en.tblDestinatarios on d.usu_remi equals r.idDestinatario
                from userCon in userGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where d.empresa == 1
                orderby d.radicado ascending
                select new Consultas()
                {
                    Radicado = d.radicado,
                    Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(d.fechaLog),
                    Radicador = u.Nombre,
                    Documento = d.documento,
                    Soporte = d.soporte,
                    Proveedor = d.remi_prov,
                    Factura = d.asun_fact,
                    Destinatario = r.Destinatario,
                    Observaciones = d.observaciones,
                    EstadoA = d.estadoA,
                    FechaDoc = Convert.ToDateTime(d.fecha_dev),
                    UsuarioDoc = doc.Nombre,
                    EstadoB = d.estadoB,
                    UserCon = userCon?.Nombre ?? "",
                    FechaEntrega = Convert.ToDateTime(d.fecha_entrega),
                    EstadoC = d.estadoC,
                    Fecha_Reci = Convert.ToDateTime(d.fecha_reci)
                };
```

analiza como se utiliza

```
join con in en.tblUsuarios on d.user_con equals con.idUsuario into userGroup
```

para despues poder asignar esa agrupacion y definir el default

```
from userCon in userGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

que se validara en el `select`

```
UserCon = userCon?.Nombre ?? "",
```